# How to fix Fedora Yum Repo

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-18

I'm tyring to do this

```
$ sudo yum install gnome-tweak-tool
```

And I get this instant response:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-18-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-18-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from pgdg91: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-18-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-18-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
```

I think I messed up the yum repo, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: First Find Which .repo file is giving problem. For that first change directory to `/etc/yum.repos.d/` after that in the terminal write this command `grep -r "yum.postgresql.org" .` and press Enter. please Post the output in your next comment.

Comment: OR try this command `yum clean all`